# how to alter main menu to add custom class

Tags: routes, theming

How do I add custom class to main menu. The main menu links are like **Fashion, Art, Life** and nodes being viewed category can be any one. I want to make the main menu item active as per node being viewed category. e.g if `example.com/node/44` -> `category = fashion` then the Fashion in main menu should be selected. I tried `MYTHEME_menu_link` and `MYTHEME_menu_link_alter` but they did not work for me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you how this works programatically, but with [menu-position module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) you can achieve exactly what you're looking for. You'll just add a position-rule for your node-types (or taxonomy item used) to highlight a parent item accordingly.

Comment: Give a try to [Menu attribute](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. you can easily add class or id to menu items.